# Menu Button/Text in Wordpress Misaligned with Sticky Menu

Tags: css, wordpress, button

I have created a CSS button on the main menu of a site that I adopted (did not design myself) and the button looks great when at the top of the page. However, once I scroll down and the menu compresses into the sticky menu, the text misaligns with the button background. The text drops down to below the button background and I'm not sure how to fix that.

I've tried adjusting the padding, instead of creating a set height & width to the button, but the padding wasn't working on the right and left side so I went back to the static size. My current button code is below.

```
.button-menu {
background-color: #0051a3;
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: central;
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }
.button-menu:hover {
  background: #fbb714;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
```

I just want the text to be centered within the button background in the vertical alignment when the menu is in scrolling mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your button has a fixed width and height but the text inside of it is going to drop down into multiple lines as that's a browser default behavior. You could try playing around with

```
.button-menu{ word-wrap: break-word; }
```

or maybe also try using a min-width and min-height instead of setting the width and height.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't seem to work either. Min-width and Min-height would be nice except for the padding options aren't working properly so then the button ends up pretty mis-shapen.

Comment: If you make a sandbox it would be easier to see whats going on.